# Translate: Mi Iesu, summo omnia tu amo

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin

Is this the correct translation for “My Jesus, I love You above all things”? I’m trying to stay true to Ecclesiastical Latin.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you mostly have the right words, you just need to get the right endings on them:

*Mi Jesu, super omnia te amo.*

Comment: Thank you. Does supra work?

Comment: This definitely sounds right to my ear

Comment: Some relevant classical citations: https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=super+omnia

Comment: @A.J. That might work, but it would be a bit of a stretch. I find *super* to be the superior choice. The classical attestations linked to in the previous comment seem to suggest this too.

Comment: *Ave regina cælorum* has *super omnes speciosa*. The trouble with *supra* is that it usually means “on top of” and even a more extended meaning tends to be on top of something else in a stack or hierarchy.

Comment: @A.J. I don't see why supra would not work. *Supra omnia* is classically attested. Of the top of my head though, I can't think of a prayer that uses  *supra omnia*, but several that use *super* plus the accusative.